# Changing the color of a 3D item based on a specified height in threejs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, 3d

I have a brain GLB model in my react app that should be fill from 0 to 100 as time of a game; chat GPT recommend me to use traverse function but it is not work :( , i want to change 50% color of this object to red and 50% to green as test, after that can change the percentage too.

this is my code:

```
const Model: React.FC<ModelProps> = (props) => {
  const { scene } = useGLTF("brain.glb");

  // Create two materials with the specified colors
  const material1 = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 });
  const material2 = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });

  

  // Traverse the brain model and apply the materials based on height
  scene.traverse((child) => {
    if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
      const maxHeight = 30; // Assuming a maximum height of 100
      const heightPercentage = ((child.position.y + maxHeight) / (2 * maxHeight)) * 100;

      if (heightPercentage < 50) {
        child.material.color.set(0xff0000)
      } else {
        child.material.color.set(0x00ff00)

      }
    }
  });

  const result = <primitive object={scene} {...props} />;

  return result;
};
```